# RuntimeException at line1 of any ServletContextListener using Netbeans and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications

I'm using Netbeans 12.3 as IDE and I was used to manage different webapplication projects serviced by tomcat.

From a day to another I cannot run any web project anymore.

I even tested with a new empty project and an empty ServletContextListener implementation

```
package stica;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class NewServletListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}
}
```

The results are the same for all my web applications:

```
30-Jun-2021 21:37:00.981 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-28] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [stica.NewServletListener]
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        at stica.NewServletListener.<init>(NewServletListener.java:1)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4640)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:692)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:537)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1592)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:356)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:368)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Jun-2021 21:37:00.981 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-28] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

The listener is loaded using web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <description>ServletContextListener</description>
    <listener-class>stica.NewServletListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

RuntimeException at line 1 with no other meaningful (at least not to me) explanations.

I tryed different versions of Tomcat (8.5.50, 9.0.44, 9.0.46) and different combination of jdk for sources, libraries etcetera (8 and 14, the base for the IDE).
I even tryed with two netbeans versions: 12 and 12.3.

The projects doesn't run, no matter what I do.

I am desperate.

Comment: Do you have a `<listener-class>` defined for **NewServletListener** in **web.xml**?

Comment: Where does `ServletContextListener` come from?

Comment: @skomisa yes it is defined in the web.xml. If the listener is not loaded the project starts without issues.

Comment: @asbachb, I can't understand what you are meaning.

Comment: Does the `NewServletListener` compile? IDE's may introduce exceptions to make classes unusable if they don't compile.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes, it does, and it's empty. I mean, is a freshly new hello world project.

Comment: Since `ServletContextListener` is not part of Java SE API it needs to be imported somehow. Normally via a maven/gradle/ant dependency or by linking your servlet container to the project.

Comment: @asbachb but i do not see any ClassNotDef or any other issue while compiling. And Tomcat server is used...

Comment: @asbachb Anyway I tryed to add EE 8 Web as library for the project. Nothing changed. Doing so I found an option in the *Run* tab of project properties which I cannot change and reports Java EE 7 Web. So I switched to Tomcat 8.5 and EE7 accordingly (http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). Once again, nothing useful...

Comment: I understand why you are trying various software combinations to get this to work, but create a clean, simple environment until this issue is resolved. [1] Since you have an EE 7 app, make sure it is built using JDK 8 (and nothing else). [2] If you run Tomcat within NetBeans it will use the same JRE that NetBeans is using, so remove any other Java Platforms you may have in NetBeans, and ensure that your default platform for NetBeans is JDK 8 (and nothing else). Then restart NetBeans. [3] Verify that JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set correctly. [4] Rebuild your app, and redeploy to Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out the cause... very stupid. I post it hoping it would be of any help for whoever else might fall in this trap.

My Netbeans uses java 14 as default jdk (that I wrongly thought was built-in - and this is why I didn't tested before as suggested by @skomisa)

In order to use it you must install **nb-javac plugin** which is normally always present because netbeans itself  prompts you to add it at the first run on a fresh new install.
Don't know why on mine it wasn't...